# simplexml_load_string: how to get openSearch:itemsPerPage in youtube's video feed?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

using `simplexml_load_string` how to get `openSearch:itemsPerPage` value from a feed in this format:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Answer (score 0):

In SimpleXML you can use the children('prefix', true) and attributes('prefix', true) functions to access namespaced content.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$itemsPerPage = (string)$xml->children('opensearch', true)->itemsPerPage;
```