# How do I parse an individual entry from XML using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse an individual element from an XML string using PHP.  The issue is that this individual element occurs before the entries start.  The XML is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed gd:kind="shopping#products"         gd:etag="&quot;lm_25heFT8yiumci9EH1kItJBpg/Sj5O9aXZ82PKpx3N2C3uQYMhNYE&quot;"     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/" xmlns:s="http://www.google.com/shopping/api/schemas/2010">
 <openSearch:totalResults>64</openSearch:totalResults>
 <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
 <openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
 <entry >...</entry>
 <entry >...</entry>
</feed>
```

I am trying to parse out the "64" in the opensearch:totalResults tag.  How do I this and assign it to a variable in php?  I tried:

```
$url = 'url of xml feed'; 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 
$entries =$xml->entry[0]->openSearch:totalResults;
      // also tried $entries =$xml->openSearch:totalResults;

echo $entries;
```

but it's not working.  Any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [simplexml_load_string: how to get openSearch:itemsPerPage in youtube's video feed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301218/simplexml-load-string-how-to-get-opensearchitemsperpage-in-youtubes-video-fee)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsimplexml%5D+opensearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register namespace in order to access these nodes:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('os', 'http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/');

$nodes = $xml->xpath('os:totalResults');
$totalResults = (string)$nodes[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php (using the $ns parameter)
that is less resource intensive.