# PHP Parse Soap Response Issue - SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, soap, simplexml, soap-client, nusoap

I'm having problems using PHP `SimpleXMLElement` and `simpleSMLToArray()` function to parse a SOAP Response. I'm getting the SOAP response from my SOAP Server just fine. I'm writing both the SOAP Client and Server in this case. I'm using **NuSoap** for the server. To me, the soap response looks perfect, but the PHP5 Soap Client doesn't seem to parse it. So, as in the past, I'm using `SimpleXMLElement` and the function `simpleXMLToArray()` from PHP.NET (http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), but can't seem to get an array.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:eCaseWSDL">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:registerDocumentByPatientResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:eCaseWSDL">
         <returnArray xsi:type="tns:ReturnResult">
            <id xsi:type="xsd:int">138</id>
            <method xsi:type="xsd:string">registerDocumentByPatient</method>
            <json xsi:type="xsd:string">0</json>
            <message xsi:type="xsd:string">success</message>
            <error xsi:type="xsd:string">0</error>
         </returnArray>
      </ns1:registerDocumentByPatientResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

PHP Code from my class ($this references apply to my library code).

```
// Define SimpleXMLElement
$xml_element = new SimpleXMLElement($response_string); // SOAP XML
$name_spaces = $xml_element->getNamespaces(true);
var_dump($name_spaces);

$soap = $xml_element->children('ns1');
var_dump($soap);

$soap_array = $this->simpleXMLToArray($soap);
var_dump($soap_array);

return $soap_array;
```

I can see the namespaces; ns1, etc. But, the array is not returned. `SimpleXMLElement` looks like it's returning an object, but empty.

```
<pre>array(3) {
  ["SOAP-ENV"]=>
  string(41) "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  ["ns1"]=>
  string(13) "urn:eCaseWSDL"
  ["xsi"]=>
  string(41) "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
}
object(SimpleXMLElement)#23 (0) {
}
bool(false)
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong. I must not have drunk enough coffee this morning. I'm tempted to just parse it with regular expressions.

Comment: Don't ... use ... regex ... argggg ... [**the pony, he comes!**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) Also, I believe this answer might help ... [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleXML creates a tree object, so you have to follow that tree to get to the nodes you want.

Also, you have to use the actual namespace URI when accessing it, e.g.: `urn:eCaseWSDL` instead of `ns1`:

Try this:

```
$soap = $xml_element->children($name_spaces['SOAP-ENV'])
                    ->Body
                    ->children($name_spaces['ns1'])
                    ->registerDocumentByPatientResponse
                    ->children();

var_dump((string)$soap->returnArray->id); // 138
```

Comment: I thought I could just pull the namespace from the XML Object Node. I guess not. Your solution worked:  $soap = $xml_element->children($name_spaces['SOAP-ENV'])->Body->children($name_spaces['ns1']);  Thank you!