# Parsing XML Feed with CDATA in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

```
<item>
  <title>Bazinga !</title>
  <ext:originalFilename><![CDATA[BVT-ch4-pt18.mp4]]></ext:originalFilename>
</item>
```

I was using `SimpleXmlElement` to parse feed, now the feed is changed and am no longer able to retreive originalFilename from the feed.
I am using this right now

```
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);
```

But this $xml doesnt have data about originalFilename.
How can i Get the CDATA as well.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been seen before. You must register the namespaces you are using, check out this SO question: [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Comment: Yes I am registering namespace s `$xml->registerXPathNamespace('c', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace('e', 'http://myvideoprovider.com/syndication/ext/');`

Comment: It was not in your question :) Can you edit with the complete code?