# How to get media:content with SimpleXML

Tags: php, parsing, simplexml

I have an XML feed that i could fetch news about cyprus on a news site.
I want to use news images and of course news itself.

Here is a sample of xml

```
 <item>
      <title>Rumlardan KKTC üniversitelerine ambargo</title>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[<p><a href="http://www.ntvmsnbc.com/id/25368624/">
          <img align="left" border="0" src="http://media.ntvmsnbc.com/j/NTVMSNBC/Components/ArtAndPhoto-Fronts/Sections-StoryLevel/Dünya/Kıbrıs/120723girne.thumb.jpg" alt="" style="margin:0 5px 5px 0" /></a> 
          Kıbrıs Rum yönetimi, KKTC'deki üniversitelerle işbirliği yapan ülkelerin eğitim kurumlarına resmi yazılar göndererek yetkilileri tehdit ediyor. Hindistan üniversitesinden ortak akademik programlara son verilmesi istendi.</p><br clear="all" />]]>
      </description>
      <link>http://www.ntvmsnbc.com/id/25368624/</link>
      <media:content medium="image" url="http://media.ntvmsnbc.com/j/NTVMSNBC/Components/ArtAndPhoto-Fronts/Sections-StoryLevel/Dünya/Kıbrıs/120723girne.thumb.jpg">
        <media:text>
          <![CDATA[<p><a href="http://www.ntvmsnbc.com/id/25368624/">
            <img align="left" border="0" src="http://media.ntvmsnbc.com/j/NTVMSNBC/Components/ArtAndPhoto-Fronts/Sections-StoryLevel/Dünya/Kıbrıs/120723girne.thumb.jpg" alt="" style="margin:0 5px 5px 0" />
            </a>
            </p>
            <br clear="all" />]]>
        </media:text>
      </media:content>
      <pubDate>Mon, 23 Jul 2012 14:27:32 GMT</pubDate>
      <category>Haberler</category>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.ntvmsnbc.com/id/25368624/</guid>
    </item>
```

The link of the xml is : http://www.ntvmsnbc.com/id/24928068/device/rss/rss.xml

Now i parse this xml with simpleXML with using below code. On this code i could prevent to display `<img>` tag with strip_ tags i could only display text data in CDATA.

In short what i am asking is how can i get `media:content url=""` into my code as I want to change thumb.jpg to hlarge.jpg in that url .

I tried `$d['media'] = $news->media->attributes();`  `'<p>'.$post['media']['url'].` but it's not working

Here is my code :

```
<? 
$NewsFeedUrl =  "http://www.ntvmsnbc.com/id/24928068/device/rss/rss.xml";

$xml = @simplexml_load_file($NewsFeedUrl);

if(is_object($xml)){
    //Rest of our code will be here
}else{
    die('Güncel Haberlere Bağlanılamıyor.');
}

foreach($xml->channel->item as $news){
    if(is_array($newsContent) && count($newsContent)==$amountToShow){
    }
    $description = $news->description;
    $d['title'] =$news->title;
    $d['link'] = $news->link;
    $d['media'] = $news->media->attributes();
    $d['cont'] = $news->description;
    $d['date'] = $news->pubDate;
    $newsContent[]=$d;
}
//$ad=array("thumb", "left");

if(is_array($newsContent)){
    foreach($newsContent as $post){

        echo '

      <article class="entry"><h3>'.'<a href="'.$post['link'].' "target="_blank">'.$post['title'].'</a></h3>
      '.'<div class="meta"><span class="date_post">'.$post['date'].'</span>'.$post['pubDate'].
      //'<p>'.str_replace($ad,"hlarge",$post['cont']).
      '<p>'.$post['cont'].
      '<p>'.strip_tags($post['cont']).
      //'<p>'.$post['media']['url'].
      '<p><a href="'.$post['link'].' "target="_blank" class="button">Devamını Oku</a>'.
      ' </article>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<p>Güncel Haberler Alınamadı Sayfayı Yenilemeyi Deneyin.</p>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/595946/831797

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `content` element has a namespace prefix (`<media:content>`), so it can’t be accessed by the usual means.

Namespace-URI for "media" is from `http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/` (check your `rss.xml` for "xmlns:media").

Try this:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $news)
{
    $ns_media = $news->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

    echo $ns_media->content; // displays "<media:content>"
}
```

**EDIT :**

I think there is some prob with the namespace uri "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"

I tried using **your** xml :

http://codepad.org/P90bOQUj  [not working]

I tried using **other** xml :

http://codepad.org/ADYveL6T  [working]

Comment: i add your suggestion as `foreach($xml->channel->item as $news){
 
    if(is_array($newsContent) && count($newsContent)==$amountToShow){
    }
    $description = $news->description;
    $d['title'] =$news->title;
    $d['link'] = $news->link;
 $d['media'] = $news->media->attributes();
 $d['cont'] = $news->description;
 $d['date'] = $news->pubDate;
 $ns_media = $news->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
 $ns_media->content;
    $newsContent[]=$d;
}` 

`echo 
   '<p>'.$ns_media.
    }` however did not work

Comment: I tried with other xml file (other namespace ) . for me it worked .. working with your xml file

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too, I tested using this solution:

https://gist.github.com/enderandpeter/6b760140bf9d2ed9620c

And it worked!

```
$content = $xml->channel->item->children('media', true)->content;

$contentattr = $content->attributes();
```