# PHP SimpleXML: How to access nested namespaces?

Tags: php, namespaces, simplexml

Given this XML structure:

```
$xml = '<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
            <channel>
                <item>
                    <title>Title</title>
                    <media:group>
                        <media:content url="url1" />
                        <media:content url="url2" />
                    </media:group>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <title>Title2</title>
                    <media:group>
                        <media:content url="url1" />
                        <media:content url="url2" />
                    </media:group>
                </item>
            </channel>
        </rss>';
$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

How do I access the attributes of the media:content nodes? I tried

```
foreach ($xml_data->channel->item as $key => $data) {
    $urls = $data->children('media', true)->children('media', true);
    print_r($urls);
}
```

and

```
foreach ($xml_data->channel->item as $key => $data) {
    $ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
    $urls = $data->children('media', true)->children($ns['media']);
    print_r($urls);
}
```

as per other answers, but they both return empty SimpleXMLElements.

Comment: The first argument of `children()` is `$ns`. You have to set the namespace URL (`"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"`), but this URL seems to be not longer valid. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648401/how-to-get-mediacontent-with-simplexml#11649046 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877048/how-to-parse-xmls-mediacontent-with-php

Comment: @Syscall, you can use the prefix if you pass true as the second parameter.

Comment: @NigelRen Oh, Right! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you echo out XML with SimpleXML, you need to use `asXML()` to see the real content, `print_r()` does it's own version and doesn't show all the content...

```
foreach ($xml_data->channel->item as $key => $data) {
    $urls = $data->children('media', true)->children('media', true);
    echo $urls->asXML().PHP_EOL;
}
```

echos out...

```
<media:content url="url1"/>
<media:content url="url1"/>
```

It only outputs the first one of each group as you will need to add another `foreach` to go through all of the child nodes for each element.

```
foreach ($xml_data->channel->item as $key => $data) {
    echo $data->title.PHP_EOL;
    foreach ( $data->children('media', true)->children('media', true) as $content )   {
        echo $content->asXML().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

outputs..

```
Title
<media:content url="url1"/>
<media:content url="url2"/>
Title2
<media:content url="url1"/>
<media:content url="url2"/>
```

To access a particular attribute (so for example the url attribute from the second code example) you have to use the `attributes()` method...

```
echo $content->attributes()['url'];
```

Comment: The missing asXML() was the main problem. Thank you!

Comment: How do I access the url attribute value though? Normally that would be $node['attribute'], but that doesn't work here.

Comment: I've added an example to the answer - but it's `$node->attributes()['attribute']`