# XML attributes and PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

how do i get the attribute value of seconds from the XML code below:

```
<yt:duration seconds='12445'/>
```

is it possible to use simplexml.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming your xml content in text.xml


    $file = 'test.xml';
    $xmlstr = file_get_contents($file);
    $xml_content = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
    echo $xml_content->attributes()->seconds;

Comment: $string = <<<XML
 <yt:duration seconds='12445'/>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);


foreach($xml->attributes() as $a) {
    echo $a;
}

output:- 12445