# xml - how to parse xml namespaces from word document to php

Tags: php, xml, ms-word

I am trying to parse XML data from word2003 xml file into PHP. None of areticles in SO I read didnt solve my problem Unfortunatelly all the structure of file has namespaces and I cant get into them to parse. I found and read many articles about geting namespaced data but it isnt clearing anything to me.

my xml file looks like this:

```
[...]
<w:body>
    <w:p wsp:rsidR="00FC2E4E" wsp:rsidRPr="00FC2E4E" wsp:rsidRDefault="00ED100D" wsp:rsidP="00FC2E4E">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:spacing w:line="240" w:line-rule="auto"/>
            <w:ind w:left="-1134"/>
            <w:jc w:val="both"/>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:sz w:val="26"/>
                <w:sz-cs w:val="26"/>
                <w:lang w:val="PL"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r wsp:rsidR="00FC2E4E" wsp:rsidRPr="00FC2E4E">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
                <w:sz w:val="26"/>
                <w:sz-cs w:val="26"/>
                <w:lang w:val="PL"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>
                           THIS IS MY SEARCH STRING
            </w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
```

I also have my php file:

```
if (file_exists('file.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    echo '|' . $child->getName(); <--- this returns nothing!
}

    [...do some modification...]
    $xml->saveXML('/stworz/dupa.xml');
} else {
    exit('Failed to open file.xml.');
}
```

I want to change content of xml (THIS IS MY SEARCH STRING), to another value, or remove it and put entire new value? How can I get into that text that is hidden in namespaced markups?
Please be aware that even root markup is namespaced!

Help in advance.

Comment: [SimpleXMLElement::children()](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children).

Comment: i used children like you can see in my edited post.. it returns empty stinrg

Comment: There is [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com).

Comment: @Kalreg you're Doing It Wrong™. Please read, and absorb, the documentation thoroughly.

Comment: Try [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Comment: @salathe - can you give me an example of what i am doing wrong? In my opinion i use children correctly.

Comment: Not conclusively, without seeing the XML you're trying to work with. However, judging from [an example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Word_XML_Format_example), you want to specify the namespace (e.g. `w`) when calling `children()`. E.g. http://so.viperpad.com/s5Njrg

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Answer (score 0):

This code *works*, but it throws heaps of warnings. You may be able to use [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com) instead.

```
<?php
if(file_exists('test.xml')) {
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load('test.xml');
    foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('t') as $child) {
        echo '|' . $child->nodeValue;
    }
    echo $xml->saveXML();
} else {
    exit('Failed to open file.xml.');
}
?>
```