# simplexml_load_string() will not read soap response with "soap:" in the tags

Tags: php, xml, soap, curl, simplexml

I know this may be a newbie question, but please humor me. When reading an xml string with "soap:" in the tags, simplexml_load_string() will not read in the xml.

given this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$s='
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap:Header>
        <context xmlns="urn:zimbra"/>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <AuthResponse xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
                <authToken>somevalue</authToken>
                <lifetime>123124123</lifetime>
                <a n="zimbraIsDomainAdminAccount">false</a>
            </AuthResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>';


print_r(simplexml_load_string($s));
echo "\n\n";
print_r(simplexml_load_string(str_ireplace("soap:", "", $s)));
?>
```

I get this output:

```
jesse@jesse-debian:~/code/zmsoap$ ./xmltest.php 
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Header] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [context] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )

    [Body] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [AuthResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [authToken] => somevalue
                    [lifetime] => 123124123
                    [a] => false
                )

        )

)
jesse@jesse-debian:~/code/zmsoap$
```

I'm just curious why this is happening, and if there is a more proper way to remedy the problem as opposed to doing a string replace.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the namespace.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A tag name with a colon in indicates the tag is in a non-default namespace. SimpleXML only looks at one namespace at a time, so you need to specifically select the namespace using [the `->children()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php).

In this case `$xml->children('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope')->Body` or `$xml->children('soap', true)->Body` should both work.

For this and other reasons, it's not advisable to use `print_r` to debug SimpleXML objects. Try [this dedicated function](http://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug) instead.

Comment: thanks for the solution... got this after long search...

Comment: @IMSoP i tried sir same here, https://3v4l.org/5IKtO#v8.0.28 but it wont work; can you please help me?

Comment: @MohibSalahuddinAyubi 1) Your XML has a different namespace than the one in this question, look at the "xmlns" part; 2) var_dump has the same limitations as print_r when it comes to looking at SimpleXML objects; and 3) if you have a new question, you need to post it separately, this site discourages discussions in comments.

Comment: @IMSoP thank you sir for your response, i appreciate that; i manage to sort this by using another response here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976218/how-to-convert-sabre-soap-api-response-to-php-array

Comment: @IMSoP indeed i posted separate query, but later on i deleted, as i found that one.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to have worked.

Read about it here: [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$s='
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="urn:zimbra">
        <soap:Header>
        <context xmlns="urn:zimbra"/>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <AuthResponse xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
                <authToken>somevalue</authToken>
                <lifetime>123124123</lifetime>
                <a n="zimbraIsDomainAdminAccount">false</a>
            </AuthResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>';
//print_r(simplexml_load_string($s));
//echo "\n\n";
//print_r(simplexml_load_string(str_ireplace("soap:", "", $s)));
$xml = simplexml_load_string($s);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
print_r($xml->xpath('//soap:Body'));

?>
```

Comment: You can do this without touching XPath and just use the main SimpleXML functions/operators. See the answer I've just added.

Answer (score 3):

simplest:

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><AddOrderResult>1</AddOrderResult></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';
var_export(json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string(strtr($xml, array(' xmlns:'=>' ')))), 1));
```

output:

```
array (
  '@attributes' => 
  array (
    'soap' => 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',
  ),
  'soap:Body' => 
  array (
    'AddOrderResult' => '1',
  ),
)
```

Comment: I don't see how can this be ***simplest***, also `json_decode(json_encode` doesn't make any sense.