# Reading a Simple SOAP XML response in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have looked for a solid working answer on this can't find one.

I am also New at SOAP, but very familiar with PHP.

I send out my SOAP request with CURL and my response comes back like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<GetFeatureResponse xmlns="http://www.supportsite.com/webservices/">
  <GetFeatureResult>**string**</GetFeatureResult>
</GetFeatureResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to save the ->GetFeatureResult 'string' in a MySQL database without the XML. Everything I try returns blank. Here's what I'm using now:

```
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);

$resultXML = simplexml_load_string($result);


$item = $resultXML->GetFeatureResponse->GetFeatureResult;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485162/simplexml-load-string-will-not-read-soap-response-with-soap-in-the-tags

Comment: Not a duplicate - I was looking for a solution to a specific problem... That post is vague in its question and doesn't not present a goal. Therefore the answer I received was much more helpful in my particular problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a built in [soap client](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php). It is a LOT easier. As long as you point it to a proper WSDL file, it will return a PHP object ready to use.

**EDIT:** Dug up an example I had around...

```
  $sc = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'location' => "https://$host:$port/path/",
    'login' => $user,
    'password' => $pass
  ));

  //$sc will now contain methods (maybe properties too) defined by the WSDL file
  //Getting the info you need could be as easy as
  $info = $sc->getInfo(array('parameter'=>'value'));
```

Comment: Then use $Info = $info->GetInfoResult; to set variable.