# SoapClient returning response with empty stdClass objects

Tags: php, soap-client

I'm running into a problem with PHP SoapClient. I have the following WSDL https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/DataService.asmx?WSDL and I'm calling the SelectDataXml. It returns the appropriate response, which includes an array of objects which correspond to the rows of data that the SQL query would return. I've checked the response in both Soap UI and through the __getLastResponse method (using the print_r routine and the NetBeans debugger window). I can see the complete response as a string but the array is being built with empty stdClasses. I've seen several answers here suggesting that caching be turned off to work around this. I tried that but nothing. I can't seem to find a way to make it build the objects correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED

The abstract superclass (sensitive data replaced with 'REMOVED'):

```
abstract class Mindbody_service {
    protected $_userCredentials = array ( "Username" => 'REMOVED', "Password" => 'REMOVED', 'SiteIDs' => array ( 'REMOVED' ) ),
        $_sourceCredentials = array ( "SourceName" => 'REMOVED', "Password" => 'REMOVED', 'SiteIDs' => array ( 'REMOVED' ) ),
        $_endPoint;

    public function __construct( $wsdl, $options = array () )
    {
        try {
            $this->_endPoint = new SoapClient( $wsdl, $options );
        } catch ( SoapFault $fault ) {
            echo $fault->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

The concrete subclass:

```
include_once ('Mindbody_service.php');

class MindbodyDataServiceResponse {

    public $Status,
        $ErrorCode,
        $XMLDetail,
        $ResultCount,
        $CurrentPageIndex,
        $TotalPageCount,
        $Results;

    function __construct()
    {
        $Status = '';
        $ErrorCode = 0;
        $XMLDetail = '';
        $ResultCount = 0;
        $CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        $TotalPageCount = 0;
        $Results = new MindbodyDataServiceResults();
    }
}

class MindbodyDataServiceResults {

    public $Row;

    function __construct()
    {
        $row = array ();
    }
}

class Mindbody_data_service extends Mindbody_service {

    private $_query = "Very long SQL command that makes sense to the server";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $wsdl = 'https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/DataService.asmx?wsdl';
        $options = array ();
        $classMap = array ( 'SelectDataXmlResult' => 'MindbodyDataServiceResponse' );

        $options [ 'trace' ] = TRUE;
        $options [ 'cache_wsdl' ] = WSDL_CACHE_NONE;
        $options [ 'compression' ] = SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP   _COMPRESSION_GZIP;
        $options [ 'classmap' ] = $classMap;

        parent::__construct( $wsdl, $options );
    }

    public function getSomething( $since = null )
    {
        $request = array ( 'SourceCredentials' => $this->_sourceCredentials );

        $request [ 'SourceCredentials' ] = $this->_sourceCredentials;
        $request [ 'UserCredentials' ] = $this->_userCredentials;
        $request [ 'XMLDetail' ] = 'Full';
        $request [ 'PageSize' ] = 0;
        $request [ 'CurrentPageIndex' ] = 0;
        $request [ 'SelectSql' ] = $this->_conditionalQuery( $since ) . ' ORDER BY Sales.SaleDate;';

        try {
            $result = $this->_endPoint->SelectDataXml( array ( 'Request' => $request ) );
        } catch ( SoapFault $fault ) {
            echo 'ERROR: [' . $fault->faultcode . '] ' . $fault->faultstring . '.';
            exit;
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage() . '.';
            exit;
        }

        echo '<p>';
        var_dump ($result->SelectDataXmlResult);
        echo '</p>';

        return $result->SelectDataXmlResult;
    }
}
```

The method in question is getSomething. The $since variable is irrelevant, it's used in the query as a cutoff date for the data being retrieved (reason for which I have a private  _conditionalQuery( $since ) method).

The output of var_dump ($result->SelectDataXmlResult) I'm getting on my browser is:

```
object(MindbodyDataServiceResponse)[22]
  public 'Status' => string 'Success' (length=7)
  public 'ErrorCode' => int 200
  public 'XMLDetail' => string 'Full' (length=4)
  public 'ResultCount' => int 0
  public 'CurrentPageIndex' => int 0
  public 'TotalPageCount' => int 0
  public 'Results' => 
    object(stdClass)[23]
      public 'Row' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[24]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(stdClass)[25]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(stdClass)[26]
              ...
          3 => 
            object(stdClass)[27]
              ...
```

EDITED

Here's the Server's response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <SelectDataXmlResponse xmlns="http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5">
            <SelectDataXmlResult>
                <Status>Success</Status>
                <ErrorCode>200</ErrorCode>
                <XMLDetail>Bare</XMLDetail>
                <ResultCount>0</ResultCount>
                <CurrentPageIndex>0</CurrentPageIndex>
                <TotalPageCount>0</TotalPageCount>
                <Results>
                    <Row>
                        <Column1>REMOVED</Column1>...(more columns)
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Column1>REMOVED</Column1>...(more columns)
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Column1>REMOVED</Column1>...(more columns)
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Column1>REMOVED</Column1>...(more columns)
                    </Row>
                </Results>
            </SelectDataXmlResult>
        </SelectDataXmlResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've removed the actual content of each Row element due to it being customer data, but they are well formed XML elements. It's those elements that I'm getting as empty stdClass objects where I should be getting stdClass objects with members that have a 1:1 correspondence to the Row element's children.

Comment: you need an example about how to call a method via soapclient?

Comment: No, that I'm already doing just fine. The problem, as I've stated above, is that the call's returning empty objects where it shouldn't.

Comment: so could you paste your code here?

Comment: Added The code, plus the output of a var_dump :)

Comment: your server will return string and it's not array? you need array result?

Comment: It seems to be. At least I'm seeing an array in the response via the output, the debugger and SoapUI. What I can't get is the contents of the elements of that array. As you can see, they're empty stdObjects, with no members whatsoever, which is wrong.

Comment: As far as I know the server can return string. try to make output as json and then send to client. because `stdObject` is a type for PHP and it's not standard for other langs like Python and so on.

Comment: It ALWAYS returns a string. The response in and of itself is not the problem, it's PHP's SoapClient parsing of this string. It's incorrectly building empty stdObjects as items of the array.

Comment: So could you paste here server output not `stdObject` , just string. and not via `var_dump` just normally `echo` or `print_r`

Comment: Edited again, raw response included.

Comment: I saw it. I'm trying to find your problem. I have created web service for many times. my code response was `JSON`(string) and my client just get me that `JSON` value and I decoded that and used that. so `print_r($result->SelectDataXmlResult['result']);` never returns null value.

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem. I'm not getting null results, I'm getting valid stdClass objects but they have no members. I'm not handling the raw response ANYWHERE. Are you suggesting I get the raw response and feed it to json_decode?

Comment: Could you create an method on the server which return "hello world" string? and test it and you should get exactly that string. means via something like `echo $output`. when you get that string correctly, try to `json_encode` a test array on the server and then test it again. on the client , try to print it via `echo $output` again and then try to `json_decode` and it should works fine.

Comment: Impossible, I have no access to the server except as consumer of the service. In any case, I already solved the problem. It would seem that PHP's SoapClient internal parser fails silently under certain conditions (which I happen to hit). What I did was discard the object I was getting and requesting the raw XML response, which I passed to the simplexml_load_string routine to get an object I could actually use. I'll post the code later on as I'm currently unable to because of StackOverflow's restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar situation, and almost pulled my hair out, but eventually I sorted it out.

From a Soap server where I can't change anything, SoapUI and Java was able to get response, but the default behaviour with PHP \SoapClient->__soapCall(...) was returning some elements as empty StdClass objects.

The solution I found is not ideal, but allows to get it done.

Basically, I wanted the raw response, so I could parse it myself, and \SoapClient->__getLastResponse() will do just that, if and only if we set options key 'trace' to 1.

So, pseudo-code:

```
$options = [
   // (login, password, etc...)
   'trace' => 1, 
];
$client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

// (prepare the data for the call...)

$result = $client->__soapCall('save', [$callContext, $name, $inputXml]);

// Because of trace = 1 in options, this will now work.
$rawResult = $soapClient->__getLastResponse();
```

Now you have full access to the response, just have to parse it.

Hope this helps someone!!

Answer (score 1):

Solution found! It seems SoapClient has problems parsing responses in some cases. I solved this by rewriting the getSomething method to discard the incorrect result and use the simplexml_load_string routine to generate the object. I based this on the thread [simplexml_load_string() will not read soap response with "soap:" in the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485162/simplexml-load-string-will-not-read-soap-response-with-soap-in-the-tags). I had tried this before but was running into a brick wall as I hadn't taken into account the SOAP namespace conflict (i.e. I was using simplexml_load_string alone :P). Here's the working code:

```
public function getSoldProducts( $since = null )
    {
        $request = array ( 'SourceCredentials' => $this->_sourceCredentials );

        $request [ 'UserCredentials' ] = $this->_userCredentials;
        $request [ 'XMLDetail' ] = 'Full';
        $request [ 'PageSize' ] = 0;
        $request [ 'CurrentPageIndex' ] = 0;
        $request [ 'SelectSql' ] = $this->_conditionalQuery( $since ) . ' ORDER BY Sales.SaleDate;';

        try {
            $this->_endPoint->SelectDataXml( array ( 'Request' => $request ) );
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($this->_endPoint->__getLastResponse ());
            $xml->registerXPathNamespace("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
            $result = $xml->xpath('//soap:Body');
        } catch ( SoapFault $fault ) {
            echo 'ERROR: [' . $fault->faultcode . '] ' . $fault->faultstring . '.';
            exit;
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage() . '.';
            exit;
        }

        return $result[0]->SelectDataXmlResponse->SelectDataXmlResult;
    }
```

Hope this helps anyone with similar problems.