# How to convert Sabre SOAP API response to PHP array

Tags: php, sabre

I am getting Sabre SOAP API response something like :

```
<soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:header></soap-env:header>
    <soap-env:body>
    <ota_airlowfaresearchrs xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.1.0" priceditincount="50" brandedonewayitincount="0" simpleonewayitincount="0" departeditincount="0" soldoutitincount="0" availableitincount="0">
    <success>
    <priceditineraries><priceditinerary sequencenumber="1"></priceditinerary>
    <priceditinerary sequencenumber="2"></priceditinerary></priceditineraries>
    </success>
    </ota_airlowfaresearchrs>
    </soap-env:body>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

But when I tried with **simplexml_load_string** I am getting a problem to convert it to PHP array. what I tried is :

```
$parser = simplexml_load_string($res);  
$parserEnv = $parser->children('soap-env', true);
$response = $parserEnv->body->ota_airlowfaresearchrs;
```

its return emptry array like :  `SimpleXMLElement Object ( )`

Comment: you are getting any error?

Comment: just an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

As ref to : [converting SOAP XML response to a PHP object or array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892639/converting-soap-xml-response-to-a-php-object-or-array)

I got the answer by doing the following way:

```
$soap     = simplexml_load_string($res);
$response = $soap->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
                 ->body->children()
                 ->ota_airlowfaresearchrs
                 ->success
                 ->priceditineraries
```

thanks @lalithkumar any way

Comment: i tried here the same: https://3v4l.org/TEmiu

But it is not working aswell :-( can you help please

Comment: i got it, it was case sensitive :-)

Answer (score 0):

From

```
$parser = simplexml_load_string($res);
```

you have to change like below:

```
$parser = simplexml_load_string($res, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

**LIBXML_NOCDATA** : You can use this function call to have simplexml convert CDATA into plain text.

Comment: No problem.i ll keep this answer like this.It may help to someone.

Comment: can you help me please, i tried here but not working https://3v4l.org/Vd3LK#v8.0.28

Comment: i got it, it was case sensitive :-)