# SOAP response is line of text instead of XML

Tags: php, curl, soap

The SOAP response I receive from the code below is coming back with the correct information, but it is in one line of text without any spaces making it impossible to gather the data I actually need from it.  Can anyone please tell me why it would be doing that?  Thank you!

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://tempsite.com?wsdl",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 
  '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:deal="http://tempsite.com?wsdl">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<deal:check soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<input xsi:type="deal:Inputs">
<CNumber xsi:type="xsd:string">9863282</CNumber>
<INumber xsi:type="xsd:string">IB5S4335</INumber>
</input>
</deal:check>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("content-type: text/xml"),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
```

Here is the XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://wsdl"> 
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:CheckResponse xmlns:ns1="http://wsdl">
<return xsi:type="tns:CheckResults">
<RtnMessage xsi:type="xsd:string">OK</RtnMessage>
</return>
</ns1:CheckResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: If you print XML and ask the browser to render it as HTML, that's essentially what you get. Hit Ctrl+U to see the actual source, or use `header()` to send an XML content-type.

Comment: Or, run this script on the command-line so you get the response into a plain-text context

Comment: Thanks.  Shows what I know.  Now, why is it that when I try to convert this to an array I get an empty array?  $sArray = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);

Comment: If you convert a string to JSON and then decode it back to string, you get the original string. Strings are just text. XML is a complex data format that you need to parse with dedicated libraries. Just because you know the string contains XML, it doesn't mean that PHP will automatically parse it for you.

Comment: What are you expecting that to do, and why? If `$response` is a string (which, if it isn't `null`) then it will be, because a HTTP response is basically always a string (or occasionally binary data if it's a binary file response, but that's not likely in this case) then encoding it as JSON won't do much. And then if it's still an XML string, `json_encode` makes zero sense cos it's not a JSON string. Demo: https://3v4l.org/17htg.  What does `var_dump($response);` show you?

Comment: var_dump gives me string(6368) and then the string in quotes.  Trying to find a way to read this response.

Comment: If it's XML, then use an XML parser (rather than a JSON parser!!). PHP comes with a couple built-in, plus there are probably other libraries available too. [start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+xml). Or maybe even better in this case, PHP also has a full SOAP client library, rather than you making raw HTTP requests with cURL. [start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+soap). Not sure how much research you did before diving into coding this?

Comment: For what it's worth, PHP has a full [SOAP](https://www.php.net/soap) library. I suspect you want to use the trick of proxying XML through JSON functions to get an array, but you forgot to add `simplexml_load_string($response)`. Plus I don't think that will work with namespaced XML (just speculating here, I don't really know).

Comment: I'll just continue reading online.  I am unfamiliar with SOAP.  I initially used SoapClient but it would not work for this particular request (although it worked for another).  It worked on another request and json_decode put it into a nice array for me.  So I tried this curl method but it has given me this data I can't sort.  Sorry for my ignorance.  I'll just keep reading.

Comment: `It worked on another request and json_decode put it into a nice array for me`...probably because something (likely the SOAP client code) had already parsed the raw XML into a PHP object first. You can then encode that _object_ into JSON text, and then re-decode it back into a PHP array. But you can't directly encode json_encode some raw XML text, because to the JSON encoder it is merely seen as a string with no special value or features, so you all you get out at the end of that is another nearly-identical string.

Comment: `var_dump gives me string(6368) and then the string in quotes`...ok but what _is_ the string? What does it consist of? Presumably it's XML data? You still haven't shown us a sample. But more than likely it will be.

Comment: simplexml_load_string($response) creates an empty object: object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { } var_dump gives the data that I want without the XML: string(6368) "0000OKDCC5BWWCDCC5BWWC041594190425ACDBABOWL,NON-LAM,5-6OZCTBRA4.002.32YNNNNUSNNNYNo138.39CTUSA1No34.90Nnone01ATLANTA2CTNALL19BALTIMORE2CTNALL35CHICAGO5CTY05:00 pm1ALL05DALLAS3CTNALL11DENVER2CTNALL08HOUSTON6CTNALL07KANSAS CITY3CTNALL10ST. PAUL26CTNALL"

Comment: If you're outputting that into a HTML web page, it's possible you still won't see the XML tags even when using var_dump. In your browser use Ctrl+U to see the raw page source and check if the XML shows up there

Comment: Yes, Ctrl+u gives me the XML. However, I still cannot access the data inside of it except with this long string of all the data together. I have tried $xml = simplexml_load_string($response); but all I get is an empty object. The SOAP response Body is like this: <SOAP-ENV:Body> <ns1:CheckResponse xmlns:ns1="wsdllinkishere"> <return xsi:type="tns:CheckResults"> <RtnMessage xsi:type="xsd:string">OK</RtnMessage>. How do I get to "RtnMessage"?

Comment: Thanks but please [edit] your question with a proper sample of the response, such that _we_ could try to load it into an XML parser. If you give us an incomplete example, it will never work for us.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://wsdl">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:CheckResponse xmlns:ns1="http://wsdl">
<return xsi:type="tns:CheckResults">
<RtnMessage xsi:type="xsd:string">OK</RtnMessage>
</return>
</ns1:CheckResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

Comment: Again, please _[edit] your question_. Important info like this does not belong buried in the comments!

Comment: I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485162/simplexml-load-string-will-not-read-soap-response-with-soap-in-the-tags will probably help you. Or try a different XML parser. _BUT_ I strongly suggest you go back to SoapClient and get _that_ working, because I can't see any obvious reason why it shouldn't, and overall it ought to be easier.

Comment: Thanks.  You've helped enough.  I will continue trying to figure this out with the links you have provided.  Sorry I thought you were telling me to edit my comment, but you meant the original message.  I don't really ever post things online so I'm a bit nervous.