# Amazon Submit Feed Error

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I want to update quantity on amazon using `Feed Api->Sumbit Feed (_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_)`

Here is my code :

```
$action = 'SubmitFeed';
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/amazon_xml/quantity.xml';

$feed = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
                <Header>
                    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
                    <MerchantIdentifier>A3QPCC6I4V1QU3</MerchantIdentifier>
                </Header>
                    <MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>
                    <Message>
                        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
                        <Inventory>
                            <SKU>6000013953</SKU>
                            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        </Inventory>
                    </Message>
                </AmazonEnvelope>';

$feedHandle = fopen($path, 'rw+');
fwrite($feedHandle, $feed);
rewind($feedHandle);

$params = array(
                    'AWSAccessKeyId' => $data['aws_access_key'],
                    'Action' => $action,
                    'Merchant' => $data['merchant_id'],
                    'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
                    'SignatureVersion' => "2",
                    'Timestamp'=> gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()),
                    'Version'=> "2009-10-01",
                    'MarketplaceIdList.Id.1' => $data['marketplace_id'],
                    'FeedType'=> "_POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_",
                    'PurgeAndReplace'=> 'false',
                    'ContentMd5' => base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true))
                );


        // Sort the URL parameters
        $url_parts = array();
        foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
            $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));

        sort($url_parts);

        // Construct the string to sign
        $url_string = implode("&", $url_parts);
        $string_to_sign = "GET\nmws.amazonservices.in\n" . $url_string;

        // Sign the request
        $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, $data['aws_secret_key'], TRUE);

        // Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
        $signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));



$url = "https://mws.amazonservices.in" . '?' . $url_string . "&Signature=" . $signature;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch); 

        //echo $url;exit;

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($response);
        echo '</pre>';
        exit;
```

But I am getting following response :-

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
</Message>
</Error>
<RequestID>105f88cb-76e2-49c0-9d33-83d6069dd119</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Can somebody please tell me how to send a xml file to api? Or I am doing something wrong ?

`quantity.xml` file is correct

**Update :-**

Code is running perfectly on [Amazon Scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.in/scratchpad/index.html)

Comment: As per your code it seems problem with your signature.

Comment: @hardiksolanki what is wrong please tell me

Comment: Why are you using signature two time in your curl?

Comment: You are pass your signature in $url variable and as well pass in your curl postfield.

Comment: I have updated the whole code now please check

Comment: I can see $url two times in your code..so remove one variable from them and run it in your browser and see what happen next?

Comment: removed now please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62243/discussion-between-hardik-solanki-and-rakesh-shetty).

Comment: $string_to_sign = "GET\nmws.amazonservices.in\n" . $url_string; Why do you have "GET\n"?

Comment: Then? What is the exact way to achieve this? @Rakesh bollampally

Comment: I'm sorry. I was thinking on the lines of aws URL signing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217097/make-a-signed-query-with-amazon-api-mws

Answer (score 0):

Amazon AWS is very fickle in its signature. [Version 2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html) requires that you use [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) to encode your data

> Add the query string components (the name-value pairs, not including the initial question mark (?) as UTF-8 characters which are **URL encoded per RFC 3986** (hexadecimal characters must be uppercased) and sorted using lexicographic byte ordering. Lexicographic byte ordering is case sensitive.

Your problem appears to be with your encoding of the signature.

```
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));
```

That will not conform to RFC 3986. PHP has [rawurlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) to do that instead.

```
$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode($signature));
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `$string_to_sign` seems to be missing the local part of the url as third line. In your case, that part is empty, so you'll just need an additional line break.

```
$string_to_sign = "GET\nmws.amazonservices.in\n\n" . $url_string;
```