# PHP : how to parse XML with nested xpath elements

Tags: php, parsing, xpath, simplexml

Here is the XML that I am working on :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:noo="http://www.myscheme.com/schema">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>A Simple Title</title>
            <noo:subcategory>the sub category</noo:subcategory>
            <noo:relatedInfos>
                <noo:teams>
                    <noo:team id="3">New York</noo:team>
                    <noo:team id="4">Las Vegas</noo:team>
                </noo:teams>
            </noo:relatedInfos>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I am doing this php code to get the two "team" but it does not work ($xml has the previous content) :

```
$xml_datas = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($xml_datas->channel->item as $item){                      
    $noo = $item->children('noo');
    echo $noo->team;
}
```

Do you have any idea why it is not working ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Comment: `noo` is not an element in that xml. it's a `namespace`.

Comment: @MarcB I think Userco realizes that.  `children()` takes a namespace URI as its argument, but one issue here is that 'noo' is a prefix, not a namespace URI.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
<?php // RAY_temp_userco.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$xml = <<<ENDXML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:noo="http://www.myscheme.com/schema">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <title>A Simple Title</title>
            <noo:subcategory>the sub category</noo:subcategory>
            <noo:relatedInfos>
                <noo:teams>
                    <noo:team id="3">New York</noo:team>
                    <noo:team id="4">Las Vegas</noo:team>
                </noo:teams>
            </noo:relatedInfos>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
ENDXML;

$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$ns = $obj->getNamespaces(TRUE);

foreach($obj->channel->item as $item){
    $noo = $item->children($ns['noo']);
    var_dump($noo);
}
```

Comment: There's not a lot of explanation here of what you've changed in the code and why. Also, assuming you're on PHP >= 5.2, you don't need to look up the namespace URI in a hash, you can use `->children('noo', true)`. Either way, of course, you're relying on the alias not changing in future.

Comment: Ok I got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"noo" is just a local alias for that namespace, and the `->children()` method (and most XML handling functions) want to know its actual global identifier, which is the URI in the `xmlns` attribute.

You need to either specify the full identifier of the namespace (i.e. `->children('http://www.myscheme.com/schema')`) or set the optional second parameter to tell SimpleXML to look up the prefix (`->children('noo', true)`. The second may be more readable, but it will break if a future document has the same schema, but gives the namespace a different local alias.

Additionally, the `team` nodes aren't directly under the `item` node, so you need to traverse further to get them:

```
// Give the namespace a readable name that won't change
define('NS_NOO', 'http://www.myscheme.com/schema');

$xml_datas = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($xml_datas->channel->item as $item){                      
    $teams = $item->children(NS_NOO)->relatedInfo->teams;
    echo $teams->team[0];
}
```

Comment: @Userco You can mark one of the answers as "accepted" so that the question shows up as "answered" on the site. :)