# Trouble parsing XML using PhP SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml, atom-feed

I am working with Google's provisioning API and I am using PhP's SimpleXmlElement to parse the XML response.

SimpleXmlElement isn't parsing the response correctly. Here's a sample.

```
<?php

$xml_response = <<<EOD
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>
  <id>https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/2.0/gethelp_example.com/helpdesk%40gethelp%5Fexample.com</id>
  <updated>2014-05-06T00:53:35.817Z</updated>
  <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/2.0/gethelp_example.com/helpdesk%40gethelp%5Fexample.com'/>
  <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/2.0/gethelp_example.com/helpdesk%40gethelp%5Fexample.com'/>
  <apps:property name='userEmail' value='liz@example.com' />
  <apps:property name='aliasEmail' value='helpdesk@gethelp_example.com' />
</entry>
EOD;
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($xml_response);
print_r($xml);

?>
```

Output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [id] => https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/2.0/gethelp_example.com/helpdesk%40gethelp%5Fexample.com
  [updated] => 2014-05-06T00:53:35.817Z
  [link] => Array
    (
      [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
          [@attributes] => Array
            (
              [rel] => self
              [type] => application/atom+xml
              [href] => https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/2.0/gethelp_example.com/helpdesk%40gethelp%5Fexample.com
            )
          )
      [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
          [@attributes] => Array
            (
              [rel] => edit
              [type] => application/atom+xml
              [href] => https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/2.0/gethelp_example.com/helpdesk%40gethelp%5Fexample.com
            )
        )
    )
)
```

SimpleXmlElement simply drops the two `<apps:property …\>` entries. I am using PhP 5.3.28.
Are there additional options/parameters I can use with SimpleXmlElement to get this to work?

Details about Google's provisioning api can be found at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/

Comment: Those are "namespaces" within XML, read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip o' the hat to [MackieeE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/292735/mackieee) and [Raf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878192/raf) for his comment on [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml) which led me to the appropriately titled blog post @ http://blog.preinheimer.com/index.php?/archives/172-SimpleXML,-Namespaces-Hair-loss.html

Here's what I had to do:

```
<?php
$xml_response = <<<EOD
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>
  <id>https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/2.0/gethelp_example.com/helpdesk%40gethelp%5Fexample.com</id>
  <updated>2014-05-06T00:53:35.817Z</updated>
  <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/2.0/gethelp_example.com/helpdesk%40gethelp%5Fexample.com'/>
  <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/2.0/gethelp_example.com/helpdesk%40gethelp%5Fexample.com'/>
  <apps:property name='userEmail' value='liz@example.com' />
  <apps:property name='aliasEmail' value='helpdesk@gethelp_example.com' />
</entry>
EOD;

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($xml_response);
$alias_email = $xml->children('apps', true)->property[0]->attributes();
$user_email = $xml->children('apps', true)->property[1]->attributes();

$alias_email['value']; // gives you the aliasEmail value
$user_email['value']; // gives you the userEmail value
?>
```