# PHP simpleXML Element parse complex XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to parse a larger xml file and it has lots of namespaces and is rather complex.

Here is an example of a the entry in the root that I would like to parse:
http://pastebin.com/zJGQZBMV

And this is my PHP Script:

```
private function importFromFile()
{
    $result = false;
    $xmlFile = simplexml_load_file($this->getSavedFile());
    foreach($xmlFile->children() as $entry){
        $entry->registerXPathNamespace("vuln", "http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4");
        var_dump($entry->{"vuln:cve-id"}) ;
        break;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

However, it does not show the CVE Id. Could it be, because of the Namespace ? I receive:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (0) { }
```

I followed: [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Kind regards, 
Richard

Answer (score -1):

You can parse large xml files with SimpleXML if you allocate enough memory to the script.

Assuming that $this->getSavedFile() represents the complete xml request with root as well as namespace declarations.

```
$xmlFile = new SimpleXMLElement($this->getSavedFile());

echo $xmlFile->entry['id'];
```

The output should be.

```
CVE-2014-0001
```

Reference: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php