# Parsing feed that's inside namespace

Tags: php, xml, parsing, namespaces

I have tried several different approaches here, but to no avail. Can someone explain to me how the following type of feed can be parsed? Below is an excerpt

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<NoticeResults xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql">
<sql:query>
    <Notice>
        <PersonId>174171199</PersonId>
        <NamePrefix></NamePrefix>
        <NameAdditionalPrefix></NameAdditionalPrefix>
        <FirstName>Donna</FirstName>
        <MiddleName></MiddleName>
        <LastName>Autrey</LastName>
        <NameSuffix></NameSuffix>
        <NameAdditionalSuffix></NameAdditionalSuffix>
        <MaidenName></MaidenName>
        <City></City>
        <State>IL</State>
        <Country>United States</Country>
        <DateEntered>2015-02-17T00:00:00</DateEntered>
        <DateCompleted>2015-02-17T00:00:00</DateCompleted>
        <DateExpired>2015-03-19T00:00:00</DateExpired>
        <NoticeText>&lt;p&gt;&lt;B&gt;PEKIN &lt;/B&gt;- Donna Lou (Morris) Autrey, 83, of Pekin passed away at 1:10 p.m. Sunday, Feb. 15, 2015, at Autumn Accolade in Green Valley.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;A graveside service will be at 11 a.m. Thursday at Lakeside Cemetery. There will be no visitation. Preston-Hanley Funeral Homes &amp;amp; Crematory is in charge of arrangements.&lt;/p&gt;
</NoticeText>
        <NoticeType>Courtesy</NoticeType>
        <Status>Active</Status>
        <FromToYears></FromToYears>
        <AffiliateSite>PJStar</AffiliateSite>
        <AffiliateAdId>Autrey_02/17/2015_4673625</AffiliateAdId>
        <PublishedBy>Peoria Journal Star</PublishedBy>
        <DisplayURL>http://www.legacy.com/Link.asp?I=LS000174171199</DisplayURL>
        <LocationList></LocationList>
        <ShowInSpotlight>0</ShowInSpotlight>
        <DateCreated>2015-02-17T01:12:37.510</DateCreated>
        <RowVersion>793618506</RowVersion>
        <GuestBookURL></GuestBookURL>
    </Notice>
    <Notice>
        <PersonId>174171209</PersonId>
        <NamePrefix></NamePrefix>
        <NameAdditionalPrefix></NameAdditionalPrefix>
        <FirstName>Lois</FirstName>
        <MiddleName></MiddleName>
        <LastName>Barden</LastName>
        <NameSuffix></NameSuffix>
        <NameAdditionalSuffix></NameAdditionalSuffix>
        <MaidenName></MaidenName>
        <City>Peoria</City>
        <State>IL</State>
        <Country>United States</Country>
        <DateEntered>2015-02-17T00:00:00</DateEntered>
        <DateCompleted>2015-02-17T00:00:00</DateCompleted>
        <DateExpired>2015-03-19T00:00:00</DateExpired>
<NoticeText>&lt;img src="/Images/Cobrands/PJStar/Photos/C7KC6NVUW02_021715.jpg" align="left" border="0" vspace="4" hspace="10" lgyOrigName="C7KC6NVUW02.jpg"&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;B&gt;PEORIA &lt;/B&gt;- Lois Mae Barden, age 84, of Peoria passed away Sunday, Feb. 15, 2015, at OSF Saint Francis Medical Center in Peoria.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Lois was born on Sept. 12, 1930, in Macomb, Ill. She married James W. Barden on June 12, 1948, in Peoria. He preceded her in death in June of 1988. &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;She also was preceded in death by her parents and 12 siblings.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Surviving are her children, Kathy (Ted) Kindred of Manito, Ill., Lynn (Allen) Simer of Nineveh, Ind., and Jim (Deb) Barden of North Pekin, Ill.; four grandchildren; six great-grandchildren; one great-great-grandson; and her two sisters, Doris Butts and Maggie Hoyt.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Lois enjoyed spending time at home with her family. She was always there to care for them when they were in need. She also enjoyed listening to Christian music, crafting, cooking and crocheting.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;A visitation will be from 1 to 2 p.m. Thursday, Feb. 19, 2015, at Davison-Fulton Woodland Chapel in Peoria. Burial will follow at Swan Lake Memory Gardens in Peoria. &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Memorials may be made to Illinois Cancer Care.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Online condolences may be made through &lt;a href="http://www.davison-fulton.com" target="_new" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.davison-fulton.com&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;center&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.davison-fulton.com" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;img src="/Images/Cobrands/PJStar/Logos/www.davison-fulton.com.jpg" border="0"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/center&gt;
</NoticeText>
        <NoticeType>Paid</NoticeType>
        <Status>Active</Status>
        <FromToYears></FromToYears>
        <AffiliateSite>PJStar</AffiliateSite>
        <AffiliateAdId>Barden_02/17/2015_102257420</AffiliateAdId>
        <PublishedBy>Peoria Journal Star</PublishedBy>
        <DisplayURL>http://www.legacy.com/Link.asp?I=LS000174171209</DisplayURL>
        <LocationList></LocationList>
        <FHIndex>10868</FHIndex>
        <FHName>Davison-Fulton Woodland Chapel</FHName>
        <FHKnownByName1>Davison-Fulton Woodland Chapel</FHKnownByName1>
        <FHAddressLine1>2021 North University Street</FHAddressLine1>
        <FHCity>Peoria</FHCity>
        <FHStateProvince>IL </FHStateProvince>
        <FHZipCode>61604     </FHZipCode>
        <FHPhoneNumber1>3096885700     </FHPhoneNumber1>
        <FHUrl>www.davison-fulton.com</FHUrl>
        <ShowInSpotlight>0</ShowInSpotlight>
        <DateCreated>2015-02-17T01:13:01.857</DateCreated>
        <ImageUrl>http://mi-cache.legacy.com/legacy/images/Cobrands/PJStar/Photos/C7KC6NVUW02_021715.jpg</ImageUrl>
        <RowVersion>793622447</RowVersion>
        <GuestBookURL>http://www.legacy.com/Link.asp?I=GB000174171209</GuestBookURL>
    </Notice>
</sql:query>
</NoticeResults>
```

I have been banging my head against the table on this all day (huge waste of 8 hours). All we have to work with in our offices are PHP (limitation by our CMS). Can someone please explain how I would go about parsing through a feed like this? I've gotten pretty far, but still can't seem to figure this out. Please also explain why you do whatever you do in order to make this work. I'll have to parse several feeds structured this way and i've never dealt with this before. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml

Answer (score 1):

You can access the elements using [DOM Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). There is an example of [looping through XML](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp) from w3schools.

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("doc.xml");

$x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;
foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item) {
  // Do whatever is needed
}
?>
```

Comment: Nice answer, but could you provide this example in your answer please?

Comment: @Victor2748 Link to the page is not enough?

Comment: No. Even if the provided link fully answers the question, it is much better if you provide an example or some content that directly answers the question, even if the content is copied from your source. Please consider reading [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), it might be helpful.

Comment: Going to give this a god now and see where it lands. Thanks guys! Will update once we've tested.