# Crawl XML which has tag:tag Namespaces

Tags: php, xml

```
<url>
    <loc>http://example.com</loc>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2015-05-11</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Some news content</news:title>
        <news:keywords/>
    </news:news>
</url>

<url>
    <loc>http://example2.com</loc>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2015-05-12</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Some news content 2</news:title>
        <news:keywords/>
    </news:news>
</url>
```

How can get `news:publication_date, news:title, news:keywords`

I can get `<loc>`'s value but `<news:` tag getting null

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://example.com") or die("Error!");

foreach($xml->url as $key){
    $URL = $key->loc;
    //What should I do here to get title, keywords, publication_date
}
```

Comment: for corrext xml file in first line a line must be such as <book xmlns:chap="http://example.org/chapter-title"> which define namespace.

Comment: I have it. For clear understanding I removed them.

Comment: in the case really read link by  ihsan

Comment: Removing the xmlns attributes breaks and changes the document. Don't do that. Please post valid XML, so it is possible to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's important you post as well the xml namespace prefix declarations of that document otherwise this can't be answered.  I suppose XML namespaces is a new concept to you and I close against a duplicate that shows how to read "element names with colons".

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to suppressing error and ask without `news:`

```
$a = '<url>
    <loc>http://example.com</loc>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2015-05-11</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Some news content</news:title>
        <news:keywords/>
    </news:news>
</url>';

$xml = @simplexml_load_string($a);

echo $xml->news->publication_date;
```

result:

```
2015-05-11
```

Comment: No, this won't work.

Comment: https://eval.in/347471

Comment: When I use `$xml->news->publication_date;` in foreach it returns null. Also I tried `$key->news->publication_date;`

Comment: I don't know why eval.in can output that. Try it and output `null`.

Comment: Yes! it don't see tag <url>, i think, because it is not in name space

Comment: This might be of your interest http://stackoverflow.com/q/595946/779320

Comment: anyway I solved problem. If XML has namespaces we need to use getNamespaces function. Then we can itarete.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem. If xml has namespaces you should use `getNamespaces()`. Clear understanding compare my question and below answer.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://example.com") or die("Error!");

$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true); // I ADDED THIS

foreach($xml->url as $key){

    $news  = $key->children($ns["news"]); //THIS

    $URL   = $key->loc;
    $PUBLISH_DATE = $news->news->publication_date; //THIS
    $TITLE = $news->news->title;  //AND THIS
}
```

**If you want to read about `getNamespaces()`:**
http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.simplexml-element-getnamespaces.htm

Comment: It doesn't work with your example :(

Comment: Do not read the namespaces from the  document. Fetch the data using the namespaces. Do not depend on the prefixes. They are only aliases and can change and are optional (on elements).