# Reading the attribute of a child element

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to read the value of `location` in the following xml:

```
<service name="xyz">
     <documentation>gSOAP 2.7.11 generated service definition</documentation>
     <port name="xyz" binding="tns:xyz">
      <SOAP:address location="http://192.168.0.222:8092"/>
     </port>
</service>
```

I am trying to reach `SOAP:address` tag  but unable to:

```
$wsdlFile = file_get_contents('./wyz.wsdl');

    if($wsdlFile) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($wsdlFile);
        foreach( $xml->service->documentation->port->attributes() as $a => $b) {
            echo $a . '-' . $b;
        }
    }
```

How could I get the value of `location`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Convert to Array like this
$wsdlFile = file_get_contents('./wyz.wsdl');
if($wsdlFile) {
    $wsdlData = json_decode(json_encode($wsdlFile),TRUE);
}
//Now you can access the address through the key=> value pair
$location = $wsdlData['location'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a `:` in a property makes it harder to get that property, but is possible:

**By index:**

```php
$value = $xml->port->children()[0]->attributes()['location']->__toString();
```

**Or by name:**

```
$prop = 'SOAP:address';
$value = $xml->port->$prop->attributes()['location']->__toString();
```

**Print all attributes of `SOAP:address` and its values**:

```
$wsdlFile = file_get_contents('./wyz.wsdl');

if($wsdlFile) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($wsdlFile);
    $prop = 'SOAP:address';
    foreach($xml->port->$prop->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        echo $a . '-' . $b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange, it works here perfectly. What error does it give you?

Comment: If you add `echo $value;` at the end, does it print nothing?

Comment: I've added an example of my suggestion in your code. Tell me if it works.