# How to read elements like <a:int> in simple xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an api service which returns xml of the below kind:

```
<KidsAges xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <a:int>3</a:int>
    <a:int>4</a:int>
</KidsAges>
```

Now here the element  denotes that there were 2 kids in the room. How can I read this while using simplexml with PHP. I just want to count the number of elements .

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Comment: Thanks. With your reference solved it like this -
count($room_value->KidsAges->xpath('a:int'))