# Php - Showing youtube videos in a table

Tags: php, xml, youtube

I'm working with the youtube v3 api. After a few tests, I realized that I need some help. When I'm trying to display the xml content, I'm just getting null values. Can anybody help me?

If you want to see the xml:

> https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=$channelid

And my code is:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("videos.xml");
foreach($xml as $content) { 
     echo $content->title . "<br>"; 
     echo $content->link['href'] . "<br>";
```

}

Xml that I want to display:

```
<entry>
Video ID <yt:videoId>Q4vSZA_8kYY</yt:videoId>
Video title <title>¡Trailer del canal! CBPrductions</title>

Upload date <published>2016-01-14T07:37:03+00:00</published>

<media:group>
Description <media:description>
LIKE PORQUE LO DIGO YO _ Suscribete!: https://www.youtube.com/user/SpanishCBProductions Dale a LIKE a mi página Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/SpanishCBProductions Sigueme en TWITTER!: https://twitter.com/CcristianN3 Y en mi poco sexy INSTAGRAM: http://instagram.com/ccristiann3/
</media:description>
</media:group>
</entry>
```

Comment: Might want to put the actual channel id in the link

Comment: You can user any id you want, for example =UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ (YouTube Spotlight)

Comment: pls copy the relevant parts of the XML into your question

Comment: Updated, if you want to see the whole xml syntax > https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCRGn72Qu0KTtI_ujNxRr3Fg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Comment: the tags with colons are namespaces. see the link above.

Comment: I tested the code for the answer you sent me and didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can register the namespace and use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).
Then for the 'media' and the 'yt' you can get the [children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) by passing the namespace.

If you want to display the first entry:

```
$url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCRGn72Qu0KTtI_ujNxRr3Fg';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$ns = $xml->getDocNamespaces(true);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('a', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$elements = $xml->xpath('//a:entry');
$content = $elements[0];

$yt = $content->children('http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015');
$media = $content->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
echo "Video ID: " . $yt->videoId . "<br>";
echo "Video title: " . $content->title . "<br>";
echo "Upload date: " . $content->published . "<br>";
echo "Description: " .$media->group->description . "<br>";
```

If you want to display the information from all the entries, you can use:

```
foreach ($elements as $content) {
    $yt = $content->children('http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015');
    $media = $content->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
    echo "Video ID: " . $yt->videoId . "<br>";
    echo "Video title: " . $content->title . "<br>";
    echo "Upload date: " . $content->published . "<br>";
    echo "Description: " . $media->group->description . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But, one question, what's the 'use' of the youtube xml schemas, w3.org and yahoo links?

Comment: Btw: for the thumbnail I have to do: $media->group->thumbnail['url'] ?

Comment: @lluiscab For the thumbnail you can use: `$media->group->thumbnail->attributes()->url->__toString()`

Comment: Ok, another question XD If I echo the descirption, it's all in one line, how can I fix it?