# PHP XML Parser for parent:child details

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, parent-child

I have the following XML schema:

```
<url>
   <loc>
      https://www.domain.com/artcile-title-x
   </loc>
   <mobile:mobile/>
   <image:image>
      <image:loc>
          https://www.domain.com/images/file_name.jpg
      </image:loc>
      <image:title>file_name.jpg</image:title>
   </image:image>
   <lastmod>2015-11-29T06:17:25+00:00</lastmod>
   <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
</url>
```

Using the simplexml_load_file functions I can correctly extract "loc". The problem is with "image". I tried many tests, but nothing. Maybe simplexml_load_file is not the correct one?

For instance:

```
//XML url location
$xmlurl = "https://www.domain.com/sitemap.xml";

//get the content in the $xmlcode var
$xmlcode = simplexml_load_file($xmlurl);

//for each "section" extracted obtain LOC and IMAGE
foreach($xmlcode->url as $single_section)
{
    //obtain the information URL->LOC
    $loc_extracted = $single_section->loc;

    echo "URL Extracted: " . $loc_extracted . "<br>";

    //obtain the information URL->IMAGE
    $image_extracted = $single_section->image->loc;

    echo "IMG Extracted: " . $image_extracted[0] . "<br>";
}
```

I have tried many tests like:

```
$image_extracted = $single_section->image->image->loc;
or
$image_extracted = $single_section->image->image->image->loc;
or
$image_extracted = $single_section->image; //and use it as an array
or
$image_extracted = $single_section->image['image']->loc;
or
$image_extracted = $single_section->image['image']->image->loc;
```

It is important to observe the XML file and how it has been built. 
From the same "url" section I have to extract both "loc" and "images:images/images:loc" detail.

I tried with this possible solution: [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

but it doesn't fit with the need to extract a simple parameter (loc) and a parameter with nodes (images/loc).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)

Answer (score 1):

> *"I tried with this possible solution: [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)*
>
> *but it doesn't fit with the need to extract a simple parameter (loc) and a parameter with nodes (images/loc)."*

I might have misunderstood the problem, but you can combine the two approaches if you like. Use `xpath()`, as mentioned in the link above, only for accessing prefixed elements :

```
//obtain the information URL->IMAGE
$image_extracted = $single_section->xpath('image:image/image:loc');

echo "IMG Extracted: " . $image_extracted[0] . "<br>";
```

Quick test : https://eval.in/526834