# Parse YouTube RSS XML data <media:description> using PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, youtube, rss

```
<entry>
    <id>yt:video:BpTW-7WGFVk</id>
    <yt:videoId>BpTW-7WGFVk</yt:videoId>
    <yt:channelId>UCqWTiyd9_A6oAOKHJkDOlZQ</yt:channelId>
    <title>
        Princess Lianna will meet Princess Cinderella | Kids Wish Network | Wish Granted | Kids Wish
    </title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpTW-7WGFVk"/>
    <author>
        <name>Kids Wish Network</name>
        <uri>
            http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqWTiyd9_A6oAOKHJkDOlZQ
        </uri>
    </author>
    <published>2015-08-18T15:09:32+00:00</published>
    <updated>2015-10-21T15:42:18+00:00</updated>
    <media:group>
        <media:title>...</media:title>
        <media:content url="https://www.youtube.com/v/BpTW-7WGFVk?version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="390"/>
        <media:thumbnail url="https://i3.ytimg.com/vi/BpTW-7WGFVk/hqdefault.jpg" width="480" height="360"/>
        <media:description>...</media:description>
        <media:community>
            <media:starRating count="1" average="5.00" min="1" max="5"/>
            <media:statistics views="34"/>
        </media:community>
    </media:group>
</entry>
```

My question is: I understand how to parse the standard tags of `<entry>` or `<title>`, but I don't understand how to parse the data for `<media:group>` or `<media:description>`. The code below is what I am using to parse just the basic info for title, id and returning it.

```
function fetch_youtube_rss($cache_len = 3600) {
  $html = "";
  $url = "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=KidsWishNetwork";
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
  for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++){
        $id = $xml->entry[$i]->id;
        $id = str_replace('yt:video:','',$id);
        $title = $xml->entry[$i]->title;
        $title = str_replace('| Kids Wish Network | Wish Kid | Hero','',$title);
        $link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$id;
        $html .= "<div><h4><a href='{$link}' target='_blank'>$title</a></h4><iframe width='295' height='166' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$id."?rel=0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>";    
}
return $html;
}
```

How can I update this to say include the description from `<media:description>`

Comment: Have you seen this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml?

Comment: Looking at it now, thank you. It did not popup in my list of prev asked questions.. thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand it. I have tried to add that to my issue here, and it just creates fatal errors.. I've tried a few different ways, but nobody's example on that post has helped me. Thanks again

Comment: Okay just got it to work using a W3 schools lesson [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_registerxpathnamespace.asp) - thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I'll update my code once I have it all working together.