# simpleXML with double colon

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to use simple XML to display the results from an XML feed in PHP.

Here is my PHP

```
$url = 'http://somefeed.xml';
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);


foreach($xml->entry as $x) {
    echo "Name".$x->title."<br>";

}
```

Here is an out take of the xml file I am trying to display

```
<entry>
        <id>test ed</id>
        <title type="text">My House</title>
        <updated>2016-03-31T22:45:06Z</updated>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <s:organisationSummary>
                <s:name>my house</s:name>
                <s:odsCode>61bv</s:odsCode>
                <s:address>
                    <s:addressLine>House Name</s:addressLine>
                    <s:addressLine>House Road</s:addressLine>
                    <s:addressLine>House Town</s:addressLine>
                    <s:postcode>House Postode</s:postcode>
                </s:address>
            </s:organisationSummary>
        </content>
    </entry>
```

With the PHP I have written, it displays the title perfectly, but I am at a loss with how to display the s:organisationSummary details. I would like them to be able to echo the s:name and each of the s:addressLine tags individually.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The part before colon is called namespace prefix. One way to access element in namespace is using `xpath()` method, for example :

```
foreach($xml->entry as $x) {
    echo $x->xpath("content/s:organisationSummary/s:name")[0]."<br>";
}
```

Related : [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)