# how to get data from xml apple rss

Tags: php, xml, rss

I wrote code that get data from http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=10/xml

```
  for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){

   $title = $xml->entry[$i]->title;  // work
   $name = $xml->entry[$i]->im:name;  //does not work

   $html .= "<br />$title<hr />";} echo $html;
```

The problem is im .I cannot get data of it . How can I solve it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml

Comment: try it with `$xml->entry[$i]->{'im:name'}`

Comment: Thank you for your response but it does not work I get empty result

Answer (score 0):

You can not access `<im:name>` in that way.

`im:` is a NameSpace prefix: to work with namespaced tags you have to use a specific syntax.

You can retrieve all document’s Namespaces URI using:

```
$namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces();
```

and you will obtain this array:

```
Array
(
    [im] => http://itunes.apple.com/rss
    [] => http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
)
```

Each array key is the Namespace prefix, each array value is the Namespace URI. The URI with an empty key represents global document Namespace URI.

`SimpleXML` has not the best syntax to work with Namespaces (IMO [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is a better choice). In your case, you have to do in this way:

```
$children = $xml->entry[$i]->children( 'im', True );
echo $children->artist . '<br>';
echo $children->name . '<br>';
```

Result for `->entry[0]`:

```
Prince & The Revolution
Purple Rain
```

The `->children` second parameter `True` means “regard first parameter as prefix”; as alternative, you can use complete Namespace URI in this way:

```
$children = $xml->entry[$i]->children( 'http://itunes.apple.com/rss' );
```

---

<sup>*...  ♪ I only wanted to see you laughing in the purple rain  ♪ ...*</sup>