# Retrieving an array of values from an XML content with a namespace in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I'm having some issues retrieving the tag values of an XML feed which has a namespace.

I've read and tried to implement some of the recommended answers on previous questions, but I still get an empty array, or a warning like

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [simplexmlelement.xpath]: Undefined namespace prefix
```

I read [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml).

The XML feed data looks like this:

```
<Session>
      <AreComplimentariesAllowed>true</AreComplimentariesAllowed>
      <Attributes xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
         <d3p1:string>0000000009</d3p1:string>
         <d3p1:string>0000000011</d3p1:string>
      </Attributes>
</Session>
```

My current code:

```
foreach($xml->Session as $event){
    if(!empty($event->Attributes)){
        foreach($event->xpath('//Attributes:d3p1') as $atts) {
             echo $atts."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the namespace:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//Attributes') as $attr) {
  $attr->registerXPathNamespace('ns',
    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays');
  foreach ($attr->xpath('//ns:string') as $string) {
    echo $string, PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

In case if you want to fetch only the values of `string` tags:

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ns',
  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays');
foreach ($xml->xpath('//Attributes/ns:string') as $string) {
  echo $string, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for these. Non of them worked, but would that be because the link in the namespace is now dead? http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays

Comment: @David, actually both of the samples work, if you load the `$xml` properly. [Example](https://eval.in/682071)

Comment: Initially I use cURL to get the data as XML (curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Accept: application/xml') and then load using: $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(str_replace("&", "&amp;", $data));

Comment: I have accepted your answer though, as you've proven that it works and my issue is different to my original question.

Comment: Namespaces do not have to be existing URLs, only valid URNs. You might have a namespace on the outer XML that does not use an prefix. (Look for an `xmlns="..."` attribute.)

Comment: Ah, Ok.. that may make more sense. There is an outer element: `<ArrayOfSession xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vista.Online.BackOffice.Api.Models.V1">
   <Session>
      <AreComplimentariesAllowed>true</AreComplimentariesAllowed>
      <Attributes xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/><d3p1:string>0000000009</d3p1:string>
         <d3p1:string>0000000011</d3p1:string></Attributes>
</Session></ArrayOfSession>`