# php DOMXpath, help getting node value

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domxpath

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante >
<cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="PZA" noIdentificacion="RRGARACION" descripcion="51571 CADENA ORO AMRILLO 45CMTS FAVOR DE SOLDAR EL ESLABON DE LADO DEL BROCHE" valorUnitario="81.90" importe="81.90" />
<cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="PZA" noIdentificacion="RRGARACION" descripcion="51570 CADENA ORO BLANCO C/CORAZON FAVOR DE SOLDAR A 16 CMTS DEL BROCHE" valorUnitario="206.90" importe="206.90" />
<cfdi:/Conceptos>
<cfdi:Impuestos>
<cfdi:Traslados>
<cfdi:Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="16" importe="46.20" />
</cfdi:Traslados>
</cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

and I need to get the "46.20" value of Traslado / importe. how can I do it? I tried something like this:

```
$xp = new DOMXpath($xml);
$data['IVA']= getpath("//@Traslados[@impuesto='IVA']/@importe");
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml) more specifically the answers. Your XML is using namespaces (the cfdi: part gives it away). And they need to be handled appropriately.

Comment: This is not valid XML, the cfdi namespace should be declared with an `xmlns` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of corrections to the XML ( adding the name space and moving the / to the start of `<cfdi:/Conceptos>`.

In the XML, you have to register the namespace in the xpath object so it can work with it and the xpath expression itself is updated...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$xml= <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="cfdi">
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="PZA" 
            noIdentificacion="RRGARACION" 
            descripcion="51571 CADENA ORO AMRILLO 45CMTS FAVOR DE SOLDAR EL ESLABON DE LADO DEL BROCHE" valorUnitario="81.90" importe="81.90" />
        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="PZA" 
            noIdentificacion="RRGARACION" 
            descripcion="51570 CADENA ORO BLANCO C/CORAZON FAVOR DE SOLDAR A 16 CMTS DEL BROCHE" valorUnitario="206.90" importe="206.90" />
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="16" importe="46.20" />
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
</Comprobante>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xp = new DOMXpath($doc);
$xp->registerNamespace('cfdi', 'cfdi');
print_r( $xp->query("//cfdi:Traslados/*[@impuesto='IVA']/@importe"));
```

Comment: D'oh!  More annoying is that I'd fixed the XPath and not copied it... oh well, main thing is that there is a working answer.

Answer (score 1):

So for starters, you're working with invalid XML. It should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="https://some/uri">
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="PZA" noIdentificacion="RRGARACION" descripcion="51571 CADENA ORO AMRILLO 45CMTS FAVOR DE SOLDAR EL ESLABON DE LADO DEL BROCHE" valorUnitario="81.90" importe="81.90" />
        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="PZA" noIdentificacion="RRGARACION" descripcion="51570 CADENA ORO BLANCO C/CORAZON FAVOR DE SOLDAR A 16 CMTS DEL BROCHE" valorUnitario="206.90" importe="206.90" />
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="16" importe="46.20" />
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

(Note the `xmlns` attribute and the correct closing slashes.)

Next, you're calling a function `getpath` which came from where? I don't know. But you're passing it an invalid XPath query. You're looking for the attribute of the `Traslados` element when you want the `Traslado` element instead. Try this out:

```
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="https://some/uri">
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="PZA" noIdentificacion="RRGARACION" descripcion="51571 CADENA ORO AMRILLO 45CMTS FAVOR DE SOLDAR EL ESLABON DE LADO DEL BROCHE" valorUnitario="81.90" importe="81.90" />
        <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1.00" unidad="PZA" noIdentificacion="RRGARACION" descripcion="51570 CADENA ORO BLANCO C/CORAZON FAVOR DE SOLDAR A 16 CMTS DEL BROCHE" valorUnitario="206.90" importe="206.90" />
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="16" importe="46.20" />
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
XML;

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xp = new DOMXpath($doc);
$xp->registerNamespace("cfdi", "https://some/uri");
$nodes = $xp->query("//cfdi:Traslados/*[@impuesto='IVA']/@importe");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    var_dump($node->nodeValue);
}
```