# PHP simplexml_load_file() function skip the XML tag which has ":"

Tags: php, arrays, xml

When I pass the XML file in simplexml_load_file to convert the XML tag into the Array its always skip the XML tag which name include the ':' value. Please advice how we convert such XML tag in to the Array.

Code:

```
$xmlArray=simplexml_load_file("WordPress.xml");
```

XML tag which not converted into the Array:

```
<wp:post_id>11149</wp:post_id>
```

Comment: please paste minimal XML example where your tags are skipped. And BTW, your xml snippet is not well-formed -> namespaces should be defined in root element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml)