# how to proccess some tags in xml?

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm trying to read an xml and its nodes with simplexml, I can open and display it in the browser with print_r for example, but I dont get take the nodes I need , can someone help me?
I need to get the value of the following tags, on tag **Descritor** I need everthing is inside it, then I´ve tag **ContasCorrentes** that is the main array, and inside it, I´ve many others tags on the same level, as **DisponibilidadeFinanceira**, **DomicilioBancario**, **CredorFornecedor** and etc...
So I´ve already gotten some values from those tags but some tags has the following format →

```
<gen:TipoDocumento>TESTEB1</gen:TipoDocumento>
```

So looks like that simplexml dont understant this part on that tag → **gen:** and on this way I dont get the data that I need :/

**follows the [LINK](https://mega.nz/file/J5IBGAzQ#G7GldcZ41yTLTl3VlKqEQw6MdwIpRrrA1m8ptnBEMV8) of the example file**

the other parts of the xml I´m taking like this for tests, probably isnt the best way to do it but this is what i got ↓

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("C:\Users\Thiago\Downloads\xml-teste.xml");

foreach ($xml->ContasCorrentes->DisponibilidadeFinanceira as $key) {
    $cont++;
    echo $key->ContaContabil . " controle = " . $cont . "</br>";    
}

$cont = 0;

foreach ($xml->ContasCorrentes->DomicilioBancario as $key) {
    $cont++;
    echo $key->CodigoAplicacao . " aplicacao cod = " . $cont . "</br>";    
}
```

So since then thanks for any help guys !

**UPDATE 1**

thanks guys, I solved my problem like this ↓

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("C:\Users\Thiago\teste.xml");
$campos = $xml->Descritor->children('gen', true);

foreach($campos as $chave => $valor){    
    echo "chave => {$chave} | valor => {$valor}<br>";
}
die;
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you can follow the [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595946/parse-xml-with-namespace-using-simplexml) to solve the problem..
It's about namespaces

Comment: Dont worry @Gauthier I just said too, thanks for the help, I´ll see link that you said when I come back to home, but since then thanks for any help, and sorry for something and for my english, and I dont intend to be rude with you ok ;)

Comment: Thanks for help Gauthier, I dont fully understand how it works on the link that you put, but throught it I can get this other [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198191/erro-ao-ler-xml-com-namespace-no-php), that solved my problem

Comment: OK that nice!!!